# BitmapFactory.decodeStream always returns null and skia decoder shows decode returned false

Tags: android, image, bitmap, skia

test image here:
http://images.plurk.com/tn_4134189_bf54fe8e270ce41240d534b5133884ee.gif

I've tried several solutions found on the internet but there is no working solution.

I'm using the following snippet code:

```
Url imageUrl = new Url("http://images.plurk.com/tn_4134189_bf54fe8e270ce41240d534b5133884ee.gif");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openStream());
```

Always getting this log:

```
DEBUG/skia(1441): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Any help?
Thanks.

EDIT:

Those images failed to be decoded are also can not be shown on a `WebView`. But can see if open in a Browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as a temporary workaround:

First add the following class:

```
  public static class PlurkInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    protected PlurkInputStream(InputStream in) {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        throws IOException {
        int ret = super.read(buffer, offset, count);
        for ( int i = 2; i < buffer.length; i++ ) {
            if ( buffer[i - 2] == 0x2c && buffer[i - 1] == 0x05
                && buffer[i] == 0 ) {
                buffer[i - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Then wrap your original stream with PlurkInputStream:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PlurkInputStream(originalInputStream));
```

Let me know if this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Sorry please try the following version instead:

```
        for ( int i = 6; i < buffer.length - 4; i++ ) {
            if ( buffer[i] == 0x2c ) {
                if ( buffer[i + 2] == 0 && buffer[i + 1] > 0
                    && buffer[i + 1] <= 48 ) {
                    buffer[i + 1] = 0;
                }
                if ( buffer[i + 4] == 0 && buffer[i + 3] > 0
                    && buffer[i + 3] <= 48 ) {
                    buffer[i + 3] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that this is not efficient code nor is this a full/correct solution.  It will work for most cases, but not all.

Comment: Thanks for helping but still get the same result. 10-28 18:36:03.970: DEBUG/skia(14676): --- decoder->decode returned false
10-28 18:36:03.970: ERROR: image is null. http://images.plurk.com/tn_5606289_30342c409d2a5a5cd747e064721464c4.gif

Comment: I'm curious why you override the method to this?

Comment: Android skia decoder does a so-called TopLeft check on gif dimensions and does not handle images that go out of canvas bounds.  By overriding the read method, we're replacing the drawing offset with respect to the canvas to zero and fooling the skia decoder to accept the gif file for further decoding.  You can look into the skia source code for Android and do a bvi check on the images against the GIF89a spec.

Comment: Btw, you might want to make sure that you use the PlurkInputStream wrapper only for images from images.plurk.com.

Comment: Yes! It finally working now! Many thanks for sharing this trick and information. One more question, what is a bvi check? Sorry I'm not familiar with image formats.

Comment: bvi is just a binary file editor like vi. You can use it to edit the image file content, and verify the format against the GIF89a spec.  That's how I did it anyway...  :p

Comment: @Wu-Man, What do you mean by "Btw, you might want to make sure that you use the PlurkInputStream wrapper only for images from images.plurk.com." and what is the "full/correct solution" version?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, partially was fixed by this class:

```
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
}

@Override
public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
    long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
    while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
        long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
        if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
              int byte = read();
              if (byte < 0) {
                  break;  // we reached EOF
              } else {
                  bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
              }
       }
        totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
    }
    return totalBytesSkipped;
}
```

}

And:

```
InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(in));
```

It helped in most cases, but this is not universal solution.
For more refer to this [bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066).

Best luck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions but did not solved my problem. After some tests, the problem of skia decoder failing happened a lot when the internet connection is not stable. For me, forcing to redownload the image solved the problem.

The problem also presented more when the image is of large size.

Using a loop will required me at most 2 retries and the image will be downloaded correctly.

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
int retries = 0;
while(bmp == null){
    if (retries == 2){
        break;
    }
    bmp = GetBmpFromURL(String imageURL);
    Log.d(TAG,"Retry...");
    retries++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
URL url = new URL(src);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
connection.disconnect();
input.close();
```

myBitmap contains your image.

Comment: Thanks but still not working. It always returns null. Another test image: http://images.plurk.com/tn_5018722_bf926743319e0ed15ccbab52a114900a.gif

Answer (score 0):

this is due to a bug in the InputStream class in Android.
You can find a valid workaround and a description of the bug here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream is = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "");
//or bitmap
//Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

For memory reasons, you must be implements BitmapFactory options like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; // might try 8 also
```

The main download bitmap function maybe like this:

```
Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {

    final HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            if(DEBUG)Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4; // might try 8 also
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream),null,options);

            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        if(DEBUG)Log.w(TAG, "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        if(DEBUG)Log.w(TAG, "Incorrect URL: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        if(DEBUG)Log.w(TAG, "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } finally {
        if ((client instanceof AndroidHttpClient)) {
            ((AndroidHttpClient) client).close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And maybe you must be implements AsyncTask like this:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is with type of color of image: your image are in color=CYMK  not in RGB

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not your case but it could be if you are trying to decode images with CMYK colorspace, instead of RGB colorspace. CMYK images, like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2w3n.jpg), are not supported by Android, and will not be displayed even in the Android web browser. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null):

[Unable to load JPEG-image with BitmapFactory.decodeFile. Returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null)