# Problem with downloading image from URL

Tags: android, bitmap

I use such code for downloading image from URL:

```
public static Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        BufferedOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

            final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
            copy(in, out);
            out.flush();

            final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
        } finally {
            closeStream(in);
            closeStream(out);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

When I send URL "http://java.sogeti.nl/JavaBlog/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/android_icon_256.png" it works fine, but when I use "http://www.hospimedica.com/images/stories/articles/article_images/_CC/20110328%20-%20DJB146.gif" it returns me null.
What's wrong with this URL?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing your own method to downlaod an image ? Android has inbuilt method to achieve this.. Just use

```
URL url = new URL("Your url");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. Something wrong with URL, but I don't know what exactly

Comment: Maybe it because of spaces in the URL?

Comment: It doesn't throw exception. just returns null in bitmap

Comment: See at the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802820/bitmapfactory-decodestream-always-returns-null-and-skia-decoder-shows-decode-retu