# Download Bitmap return nulls sometimes

Tags: android

I have some code that retrieves an image from the web using this method

```
public  Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl){
    URL myFileUrl =null;          
    try {
        myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setReadTimeout(500000000);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", " Download image failed"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, sometimes it returns null with no error, and sometimes it works.

I tried setting the timeout to a large number and it still doesn't have an error.

Comment: It seems like the only way for that code to return null is if there is an io exception, do you see a stack trace?

Comment: I did a try and catch on exception but it doesn't return any error just returned null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802820/bitmapfactory-decodestream-always-returns-null-and-skia-decoder-shows-decode-ret seems to be a bug

Comment: Looks like a bug.. I am dealing with the same challenge when trying to retrieve location geopoints from Google map service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this bit of code in your catch clause. It will display a toast msg with the error. You are probably not getting out all the time.

```
catch(IOException e) {
Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
```

//Toaster on high-----------------//

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "IOException:  " + e.getMessage();
int dur = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
Toast.makeText(context, text, dur).show();
```

Comment: that suc*&, I catch I/O "Service Exceptions" with that block when I can't connect.